# Como usar a biblioteca JavaScript pdf.js no Selenium com Java através da clase JavaScriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, jspdf

Encontrei está biblioteca que faz exatamene o que preciso, extrair o texto do PDF e transformar em uma String. http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/ https://github.com/hubgit/hubgit.github.com/tree/master/2011/11/pdftotext

Pelo que pesquisei (muito), me parece que a versão abaixo é a mais recente do pdf.js. Porém, não consigo após abrir o arquivo pdf no navegador, fazer com que essa biblioteca seja chamada e então use os métodos dela para copiar o texto. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Pesquisei muito durante 2 seguidos, de fato não sou grande conhecedor de js, mas encontrei está forma https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript que parece ser a ideal de como implementar, porém, não consegui adaptar para o JavascriptExecutor de Selenium.

Eis minha tentativa tentando chamar da mesma forma que o index do primeiro exemplo http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/.

```
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/arquivo.pdf");

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    String script1 = "id=\"pdf-js\"";
    String script2 = "src=\"projeto/src/test/resources/js/pdf.js\"";
    String script3 = "PDFJS.workerSrc = cslight/src/test/resources/js/pdf.js";
    String script4 = "src=\"/projeto/src/test/resources/js/app.js\"";
    String script5 = "var app = new App;";

    jse.executeScript(script1);
    jse.executeScript(script2);
    jse.executeScript(script3);
    jse.executeScript(script4);
    jse.executeScript(script5);
```

Abaixo o erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: PDFJS is not defined
```

(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'NC0048', ip: '10.13.30.196', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7), userDataDir=C:\Users\ICARO~1.PRA\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir17892_11337}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=65.0.3325.181, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 757fa21a22500f6618317bc12d5799ce
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
    at br.com.conductor.test.GenericTester.tester(GenericTester.java:40)
    at br.com.conductor.test.GenericTester.main(GenericTester.java:61)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue duas API's que você pode adicionar no seu projeto maven para ler PDF:

com.itextpdf
    itextpdf
    5.5.13


    org.apache.pdfbox
    pdfbox
    2.0.9

https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1

https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/examples.html

package testcases;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

public class PdfTest {

```
private final String pdfUrl = "http://files.isec.pt/DOCUMENTOS/SERVICOS/BIBLIO/teses/Tese_Mest_Marcio-Carvalho.pdf";
private final String pdfPath = "/home/diamaral/Documentos/diamaral/test.pdf";

@Test
public void lerConteudoPdfUsandoApiIText() throws IOException {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfUrl); 

    System.out.println("\n\n---------API ITEXT-----------------------------"+
            PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader,1));
}

@Test
public void lerPdfUsandoApiPdfBox() throws IOException {
    RandomAccessRead doc = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(new File(pdfPath));
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(doc);
    parser.parse();
    PDDocument pdfDoc = parser.getPDDocument();
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    System.out.println("\n\n---------API PDFBOX-----------------------------"
                        +stripper.getText(pdfDoc));
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Sensacional! Resolveu meu problema em minutos. Muito obrigado mesmo!